# how to hide the data whose date have been passed

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to hide the date which have been passed.

```
"SELECT * FROM " . USER_TABLE_NAME . " AS cu 
 INNER JOIN " . JOB_TABLE_NAME . " AS jb 
 ON jb.user_id = cu.user_id 
 WHERE cu.user_id = '$userID' 
 ORDER BY jb.job_date DESC, jb.job_tea_time DESC";
```

Rightnow I'm getting all the data `order by date.`

The date is stored in `VARCHAR` and i am not suppose to change that.

Thanks,

Comment: Very difficult to understand what you're asking.  Perhaps some example data would help to illustrate your problem?

Comment: You mean you want details from today(current day) onwards?

Comment: @user3378765: By saying `whose date have been passed`, do you mean that the current date is ahead of them?

Comment: Where is the date you are passing?

Comment: yes, exactly @Blank Head

Comment: jb.job_date is for getting date @kimbarcelona

Comment: Do you have an example of jb.job_date? Is it in a format like "30 Dec 2013, 1438hrs" or is it a number or a timestamp like 1397196232

Comment: it is the format of date 04/20/2014 (mm/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be helpful

```
"SELECT * FROM " . USER_TABLE_NAME . " AS cu 
 INNER JOIN " . JOB_TABLE_NAME . " AS jb 
 ON jb.user_id = cu.user_id 
 WHERE cu.user_id = '$userID' AND STR_TO_DATE(jb.job_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= now()
 ORDER BY jb.job_date DESC, jb.job_tea_time DESC;
```

Comment: Sorry, Blank Head no Output.. Thanks for reply

Comment: How did you save your date field? whats the date format?

Comment: I didn't mean the data type. I mean the format. Just as 12/02/2013 or anything like that

Comment: 10/18/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: which one is the 18th month?!!:P I guess its 18/10/2013.

Comment: It's still returns empty table: "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0008 sec)"

Comment: Give me your table fields then

Comment: 1 job_id         int(11) 
2 user_id  int(11)  
3 job_date varchar(100)
4 job_tea_time varchar(100)
5 customer_name varchar(255)
6 caddy_job varchar(100)
7 job_note text 
8 status  int(11)
9 created_date datetime

Comment: Is there any value in the date field which is greater than today is date in your DB?
If yes , whats that value?

Comment: if you are asking me about the date, than there are lots of future dates.. 13/04/2014, 14/04/2014... so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtodate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the string to date - afterwards you can easily compare it via date functions.

Comment: @user3378765 The documentation of [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) provides the list with specifiers. You've got to build your format-string according the format that's in your table. It's a very bad idea to store dates in varchar-columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date string (varchar) to unix timestamp using mysql function unix_timestamp and for comparison less than today's date , you can use strtotime('today') in php

```
"SELECT * FROM " . USER_TABLE_NAME . " AS cu INNER JOIN " . JOB_TABLE_NAME . " AS jb 
    ON jb.user_id = cu.user_id 
WHERE cu.user_id = '$userID' AND unix_timestamp(jb.jobdate) > " . strtotime('today') . "
    ORDER BY jb.job_date DESC, jb.job_tea_time DESC";
```

This should work. If found any issue, let me know!

Comment: Hey Pankaj, thanks for reply.. but it's not working, now it doesn't show any output.

Comment: I just edited the answer, there was some syntax mistake. I hope you corrected that!

Comment: @user3378765 : It should work. You can try with valid data according to your query. Additionally print the query and run it on mysql console or phpmyadmin whatever you are using. There may be logical errors in that. You can try the same condition for jb.job_tea_time too.

Comment: Using the last edited version, "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0008 sec)"

Comment: Do you have valid records for today ? It should surely work. and there is no error in mysql query. Once you have records here at mysql after that try in php. but make sure you have valid records.

Comment: trust me pankaj there are lots of values in the database for today, tomorrow and yesterday..